# Is it possible to sort tasks by the order of a Custom attributes of a Custom Field?

Tags: tasks, ms-project-2013

This is not as simple as it seems to be.

I have multiple *tasks*. That I group following a *Custom field* (text), called *TypeC*. The custom field can have *Custom attributes* that are already defined like `{P,Ar,D,B}`.

I saved my custom *group by* in the drop menu so I can use it and reuse it. But I don't get the order of the *Custom attributes* -> `P` then `Ar` then `D` then `B`. I rather get an alphabetical order -> `Ar` then `B` then `D` then `P`.

Is there a way to custom sort that in `Microsoft Project 2013` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to number the attributes with numbers to get them to sort in a non-alphabetic manner.  So 1-P, 2-Ar, 3-D, 4-B.

Comment: And how to do that in *lookup* ... ?

Comment: Edit the lookup field values.

Comment: it worked, unfortunately a software that cost >1000$  does not have such functionality ...

Comment: I don't follow.  It worked - what's your question?

Comment: yes, it worked,. .... never mind